# If unset assign other var

Tags: bash

In some languages  you can assign something to another var if it is unset. Like so:

```
// a should be === c
var a = b | c // b is empty and c=1
```

In bash you can seta  default value like so:

```
a=${b:-c}
```

But this will give you `c` and not the value of `c`

I've tried

```
a=${b:-$c}
```

but that doesn't work how do I do this?

Comment: It should; `c=5; a=${b:-$c}; echo $a` outputs 5.

Answer (score 2):

`a=${b:-$c}` works fine, provided that `c` is set to some value. otherwise `a` will be set to `null`

```
c=4
unset b
a=${b:-$c}
echo $a
```

gave output as `4` value of `c`

```
unset b
unset c
a=${b:-$c}
echo $a
```

will give output (null)

Answer (score 1):

```
${parameter:=word}
```

From man bash:

```
Assign Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion
of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then
substituted.
```

---

```
${parameter:-word}
```

```
Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion
of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is
substituted.
```